# Python read from txt and save into mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I need some help with my weather station. I would like to save all results into mysql database, but at the moment i've got all results in txt files.

Can you help me to write a script in python, to read from txt file and save into mysql?

My txt file (temperature.txt) contains data and temperature. It looks like:

```
2013-09-29 13:24 22.60
```

I'm using python script to get temperature and current time from big "result.txt" file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time



buffer = bytes()

fh = open("/home/style/pomiar/result.txt")

for line in fh:

    pass

last = line

items = last.strip().split()



fh.close();


print time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), items[1]
```

But I would like to "print" that into mysql table. I know how to connect, but I dont know how to save data into table.

I know I need to use:
    #!/usr/bin/python

```
import MySQLdb

# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","user","password","weather" )
```

And I've got my database "weather" with table "temperature". Dont know if I made good table (first - datatime, second varchar (5)). And now I need python script to read from this file and save into mysql.

Thanks a lot for ur support.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far and where you got stuck. We are not writing code for you based on some vague requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Next step is simple:

```
from contextlib import closing

with closing(self.db.cursor()) as cur:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO table1(`measured_at`,`temp`) VALUES(%s, %s)", (measured_at,  temp))
    self.db.commit()
```

P.S. It looks like you ask this question because you didn't make your homework and didn't read  via ANY python tutorial how to work with MySQL.